# bind array from template to controller with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, bind

Hi I have a problem with bind data from template to controller with angularjs

The first I have object (**edited**)

```
$scope.data =  {

               }
```

After that I bind it to html

```
<input ng-model="data.item.test[0].value" />
```

But I controller I get

```
{
    item: object() {
        0: object() {value: "ok"}    
    }
}
```

What is need is

```
item = array(0: object())
```

How can I do it

Comment: If you want item property to be an array, define it as an array, not as object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change mode structure in controller:

```
$scope.data = {
    "item": []
};
```

and in HTML use

```
<input ng-model="data.item[0].value" />
```

Then the model object will become something like this:

```
{
  "item": [
    {
      "value": "ok"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Demo:**  http://plnkr.co/edit/u66QJhYiduk668C54fOb?p=preview

Comment: Can you help me again? I just updated question. problem is I have too many fields. And I can't set it manual,

Comment: Not clear what your update was and what is the question with many fields. Can you elaborate?

Comment: In the begining $scope.data =  {
                         "item" : {}
               }

Comment: But now it is $scope.data =  {  }

Comment: okay, so what is the problem? There is a demo in my answer, feel free to update it to problematic version and share so I could take a look.

Comment: ah, my problem is I don't want set it manually. But if that is the only way, I will do it/

Comment: You don't have to set it in controller if I understand you correctly. Angular will create missing model object for you when necessary: http://plnkr.co/edit/BmuhHEH0B0aHThcUvWr5?p=preview